# Flip image when swiping in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, flip

i need to create a image album.but i need to flip the image when we swipe for next . here is a link what exactly i want.can any one help me to get that code.i search for the code but i didn't get it.the above link shows the demo only .if the code is not available can any one help me with the page transformation animation like this for the viewPager . please help me.thanks in advance..
link http://openaphid.github.io/blog/2012/12/12/flipview-for-android-v0-dot-9-6-released/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for [link](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip)

Comment: but when i run this in my android it showing some exception

Comment: what kind of exception?

Comment: [16711] Connection closed by host (err = 104), possibly due to exception: App cannot continue with current context. Exiting.

Comment: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000123 (code=1), thread 16711 (Thread-237)

Comment: these are the exception

Comment: This error will be faced in case of memory management in native side. can you show me you logcat?